# In this case, can 'be verb' be omitted?

Tags: conjunction-reduction

I am a student learning English.
I learned that repetitive subject or verb can be omitted when multiple sentences are connected with conjunctions. Then I found this sentence.

> Thanks to his action, they weren't destroyed or weren't taken overseas.

'Weren't' is repeated, so can I omit the second one? Or should it be omitted, not an option?
If it's an option, is it just up to the writer's writing style?

Answer (score 3):

It is more common to omit the second "weren't" (and probably also because of grammatical reasons), as otherwise it may sound repetitive. Also, if we have something ending in "not" or "n't" before two things, the "or" should be "nor".

Therefore, we have

> Thanks to his action, they weren't destroyed nor taken overseas.

Comment: I'd say that "or" is fine.

Comment: I'd say "or" is better unless you also use "neither".

Comment: It's fine with ***nor***. We're ***more likely*** to use ***nor*** after ***neither***, but the construction ***not X nor Y*** [has always been perfectly common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+seen+nor%2Cneither+seen+nor&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10)